# Calling a boolean function but getting error "no matching function to call"?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, boolean

I am trying to declare 2d arrays dynamically and fill them with random numbers and then create a function that will compare the elements in two 2d arrays and if they were equal it will return true

However, i keep getting error when trying to call the boolean function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool isEqual(int *arr1[], int *arr2[], bool &eq, int row, int col){

for(int r = 0; r<row;r++)
{
    for(int c= 0; c<col;r++)
    {
        if(arr1[r][c]==arr2[r][c])
            eq = true;
    }
}
return eq;
 }

int main()
{
const int R = 3;
int * arr2D_a[R];
int * arr2D_b[R];
int C;

cout << "Enter number of columns: ";
cin >> C;
for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
    arr2D_a[r] = new int [C];
    arr2D_b[r] = new int [C];
}



for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < C; c++) {
        arr2D_a[r][c] = rand() % 2;
        arr2D_b[r][c] = rand() % 2;
    }
}

bool result = false;
isEqual(arr2D_a,arr2D_b,result,R,C);

if (result==true)
    cout << "\nThe 2 array are the same!\n";
else
    cout << "\nThe 2 array are the differernt!\n";

for (int c = 0; c < C; c++) {
    delete[] arr2D_a[C];
    delete[] arr2D_b[C];

}
for (int r = 0; r < R; r++)  {
    delete[] arr2D_a[r];
    delete[] arr2D_b[r];

}


system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You are using the same variable `r` for your two `for` loops. Variable that is not used inside the loop scope. Is it on purpose ?

Comment: didnt notice it ! and i wasnt able to call the function

Comment: And why are you passing a bool in by reference and not reusing it for the output? Bad design!

Comment: You have a typo in `for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
    arr2D_a[R] = new int [C];
    arr2D_b[R] = new int [C];
}`.  You are using the wrong `r` for the array index.

Comment: `delete[] arr2D_a[C];` -> `delete[] arr2D_a[c];`

Comment: @NathanOliver probably the "error" OP mentionned, runtime error and not compile time?

Comment: Don't edit your question in a way that invalidate existing answer.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher IDK.  There are so many mistakes/typos it's hard to know without  knowing what error the OP has.

Comment: Avoid raw owning pointer, prefer `std::vector`.

Comment: `arr1[r][c]` on an `int*`  doesn't work, you don't have 2D pointers here. I think it's time to go back to your blank sheet, with a good C++ book, and start from scratch.

Comment: @NathanOliver indeed, compilation would not work because of the 2D indirection on a 1D array, so we are at, what, 4 or 5 mistakes?

Comment: Try `bool isEqual(int** arr1, int** arr2, bool &eq, int row, int col)`

Comment: There's no need to pass the `bool` in as a parameter, just declare a local `bool` in the function and return it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** i took the liberty of rewriting your code. the code i posted, compiled in VS2017.

your compare seems kind off

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool isEqual(int* arr1[], int* arr2[], const int row, const int col) {

    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            if (arr1[r][c] != arr2[r][c])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    const int R = 3;
    int * arr2D_a[R];
    int * arr2D_b[R];
    int C;

    cout << "Enter number of columns: ";
    cin >> C;
    for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
        arr2D_a[r] = new int[C];
        arr2D_b[r] = new int[C];
    }



    for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < C; c++) {
            int value = rand();
            arr2D_a[r][c] = value % 2;
            arr2D_b[r][c] = value % 2;
        }
    }

    bool result = isEqual(arr2D_a, arr2D_b, R, C);

    if (result)
        cout << "\nThe 2 array are the same!\n";
    else
        cout << "\nThe 2 array are the differernt!\n";

    for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
        delete[] arr2D_a[r];
        arr2D_a[r] = 0;
        delete[] arr2D_b[r];
        arr2D_b[r] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1. you have to declare your parameters for your function right. **bool isEqual(int** arr1, int** arr2, bool &eq, int row, int col)** because you have a 2D array
2. check if the values diff, escape the function as soon as they do. there is no need for a bool variable
3. i dont know if it was intentional, but your init of the arrays. there was no way that they could have matched. you called **rand()** everytime, so the values can't match
4. was a little thing with the delete of the columns. you have to use your index **c** not the variable **C**
5. this i did not change... pls don't use **using namespace std;**. this namespace is so enormously huge. when you define your own functions, you can run into undebugable errors, when you declare a function with a name that exists.

**EDIT 2**

I totally removed the bool in the function call...

**EDIT 3**

to leave this program for good you have to provide a return value

another mistake was, you must not make the second delete loop. since you have not dynamically allocated this memory.

**EDIT 4**

reworked the function to please all the compilers =)

**EDIT 5**

i hope its the last edit for this answer^^ i fixed the memory issue. i checked it with dr. memory and he says, everything is ok :D

Comment: even if declared eq in main? as i am passing it as refrence

Comment: sry... i did overread this... put its better to declare the return in the function itself. and btw... native c++ types should be passed copy-by-value.

Comment: what do you mean with native c++ types?

Comment: every type you can declare variables with, which come "built in" - like int, bool, float, ...

Comment: i get error saying subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector?

Comment: @skratchi.at  not when they are modified in place, that's the point of OP's original code. But it was still bad because it mixed two approaches. Then now you need also to update `bool result = isEqual(arr2D_a,arr2D_b,R,C);` and of course fix all the rest of the mistakes.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher ok have to do some research on that. removed the comment as anyhow I confused things a bit, OP seems to use it as out parameter (but at the same time returns it..)

Comment: @user463035818 I'm confused by it as well ;)

Comment: It compiles in VS, but not in other compilers, clang and gcc give all kind of errors :( I get this error: `error: invalid conversion from ‘int**’ to ‘const int**’ [-fpermissive]
     bool result = isEqual(arr2D_a, arr2D_b, R, C);`

Comment: You cannot pass unknown size array as constant. So your problem is not `* arr[]` or `**arr[]` it is `const` that is an issue.

Comment: @skratchi.at good job :). try entering 55 as input for `C`. you have to fix `segfault` as well and you answer is perfect!!!! Then I can delete mine

Answer (score 2):

The answer above fixes most of the issues, but you will get `segfault` her.

```
for (int c = 0; c < C; c++) {
    delete[] arr2D_a[c];
    delete[] arr2D_b[c];

}
```

if you put something greater than 3 up here

```
std::cin >> C;
```

What you need to do is leave the second loop:

```
for (int r = 0; r < R; R++) {
    delete[] arr2D_a[r];
    delete[] arr2D_b[r];
}
```

because you allocated `C` amount of space in every `arr2D_a[r]` and `arr2D_b[r]`.

Comment: having single letter variables, is very confusing... i checked your changes with a leak detector and he said, its ok now^^

Comment: @skratchi.at good job!!!!! LOL, I know single letter thing is confiusing :(  but world is not perfect.